# Отрицательные элементы увеличить на 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код, который должен отрицательные элементы увеличить на 2

```
x = int(input())
n = len(x)
for i in range(n):
if x[i] < 0:
    x[i] += 2
print(x)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что я делаю не правильно, укажите пожалуйста на мою ошибку

Comment: "Что я делаю не правильно" - даешь неправильные заголовки вопросам. И не читаешь сообщения об ошибках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В своем коде Вы пытались преобразовать строку в с несколькими числами в `int`. А это делается так: `"1 2 3 4 5".split()` - сначала разделяем через пробел, берем отдельно все числа, как строки. А потом для каждой такой строки преобразовываем ее в `int()`.

```
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = len(x)

for i in range(n):
    if x[i] < 0:
        x[i] += 2
    print(x[i])
```

Вариант в одну строку:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x) + 2 * (int(x) < 0), input().split())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вводите значение через пробел и `int` не может их превратить в число

разделяем значение по пробелу:

```
input().split()
```

Далее с помощью цикла превращаем все значения в число

```
res = []
for el in input().split():
    res.append(el)
```

Но лушче испольщовать `map`

```
res = list(map(int, input().split()))
```